# Postfix piping to a ruby script. Is a new ruby process created for each email?

Tags: postfix, ruby

I'm writing a ruby script to process incoming email for a specific email address using a transport.

```
Postfix transport table
me@example.com      ruby-script

Postfix master file
ruby-script unix    -   n   n   -   -   pipe
      flags=    user=zimbra argv=/usr/bin/ruby  /opt/zimbra/ruby-script.rb
```

Let's say 10 emails are piped to the ruby script within the same timeframe. Does postfix create 10 ruby-script.rb processes to handle those 10 emails or how does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, postfix will spawn a new process for each.
But you can control the parallel delivery with `ruby-script_destination_concurrency_limit=2` for example, meaning 2 parallel delivery to ruby-script transport.

Comment: if I set the limit to 2 what happens with the other 8 emails? Are they bounced back to the users?

Comment: No, they are queued up until the running scripts finish up.